# scrapy spider does not need aws secret to access s3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, scrapy

Update: Original Problem [scrapy spider with FEED_URI to s3 does not work in EC2 instance (code works locally)] solved because I figured out I didn't configure aws config to add my AWS_ACCESS credential into the system. Then I have a follow up question that what's the point to configure the credential into the spider? I comment it out then it still works.

My local scrapy spider upload json report to the s3 bucket successfully. However when I move the code to EC2 instance, it still runs but nothing is updated to s3 bucket. I want to know how to set it up right either in scrapy or aws.

I already set the IAM role of my EC2 instance to have full access to S3, btw I don't think it should have any issue as it is using AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to access my s3 bucket.

```py
# this is my spider.py

class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "foobar"
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
        'FEED_URI': 's3://foobar/' \
            +'Year=' + str(today.year) \
            + '/Month=' + str(today.month) \
            + '/Day=' + str(today.day) \
            + '/' + today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S")+'.json'
        # 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID': 'foo',
        # 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY': 'bar'
    }
```

expect output should be upload json to s3 bucket, which will run successfully as my local run.

Comment: Do you get any error in EC2?

Comment: @Gallaecio no I don't. The output is same as local in the terminal, just nothing uploaded into s3.